# How can I log into my Raspberry Pi Samba share from Windows?

Tags: raspbian, windows

I'm trying to set up an SMB share on my network using Samba.

I followed the directions [here](http://simonthepiman.com/how_to_setup_windows_file_server.php) as well as I could as I have Raspbian installed on my Pi. When I plugged in my USB drive it automounted to `/media/Media/` so I skipped the first part.

What I did was the following:

1. `sudo -i`
2. `apt-get update`
3. `apt-get upgrade`
4. `apt-get install samba`
5. `apt-get install samba-common-bin`
6. Edited samba config

   ```
   Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf  
   rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)  
   Processing section "[usb]"  
   Loaded services file OK.  
   Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE  
   [global]  
       workgroup = WORKGROUP  
       server string = %h server  
       map to guest = Bad User  
       obey pam restrictions = Yes  
       pam password change = Yes  
       passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u  
       passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .  
       unix password sync = Yes  
       syslog = 0  
       log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m  
       max log size = 1000  
       dns proxy = No  
       usershare allow guests = Yes  
       panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d  
       idmap config * : backend = tdb  
       valid users = %S  
       create mask = 0700  
       directory mask = 0700  

   [usb]  
       comment = USB Share  
       path = /media/Media  
       read only = No  
       create mask = 0777  
       directory mask = 0777  
       guest only = Yes  
       guest ok = Yes
   ```

So the setup appears OK, I can see the files in `/media/Media` on the Pi, I can see `RASPBERRYPI` in my workgroup from my Windows7 box. But when I try to access it I get a logon failure. I also have a 2nd pi with RaspBMC installed and I also cannot access the SMB share from there either.

Is there something else I need to do in Samba to get this working?

**Edit:**
I did some more work on this last night.
I added a new user to the Raspberry, set a password, added a new user to Samba, set the password and added the following lines.

```
[global]  
security=user  
[usb]  
allow users biff
```

(or something similar I forget the exact syntax)

And now I've managed to get an error like... "You do not have authorization to access this share". I'm thinking perhaps I'll work on my Pi directly tonight instead of using putty and perhaps there is something I'll be able to see when using a text editor instead of `vi`.

**Resolution**

Ok I finally resolved this. The problem was that I could not use the pi login to access the pie using smb and also that I could not change the permissions of the automounted /media/Media drive.
I found my solution here https://superuser.com/questions/57092/cant-change-permission-ownership-group-of-external-hard-drive-on-ubuntu
I had to install ntfs
`sudo apt-get install ntfs-config`
and then I ran the ntfs configuration tool which just gives anyone read/write access.

Not the best solution but it is sufficient in my case for sharing files on the network.

Comment: what is the exact error you get on your windows box?

Comment: @Mose `The specified network password is not correct.`

Comment: Not related to what you have asked, but you can also mount your Pi on Windows over SSH - http://dokan-dev.net/en/download/#sshfs

Comment: @LordLoh. Thanks Loh, my ultimate goal here is to have an always on network share that my Raspbmc, Wii and Windows machines can access so I don't have to have my main computer on all the time.

Comment: Can you try this? Give the Username as RASPBERRYPI\pi(where pi is a user in raspberry pi) and password as the password of the user.PRobably you have already tried this but just in case :)

Comment: @SteveIrwin Thanks, I haven't tried that, I'll give it a shot tonight.

Comment: @BiffMaGriff-Did any of the suggestions work for you?

Comment: @SteveIrwin No joy yet. I think ppumkin's update will work but I also think that I have an underlying permissions problem. I have a few things I am going to try before posting my success or dead end. I need this weekend to work on it as it has been a busy week.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to setup samba to allow anonymous/everyone/guest to be able to connect. This takes away the error message you.

This is deprecated ...

```
security = share
...
...
guest account = nobody
```

Use this instead

```
[global]
    workgroup = workgroup
    server string = MY-SERVER
    security = user
    map to guest = Bad User
    username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
    guest ok = yes

[to_password_protected_folder]
    path = /home/tom
    writeable = yes
    valid users = username1

[no_password_folder]
    path = /home/nobody
    writeable = yes
```

Possibly some other settings in the config need relaxing.. Samba in Linux is more secure than in Windows. The irony ... :-]

I hope that helps you.

Comment: I'm getting `security=share is deprecated` and I am still unable to access the share.

Comment: Things changed so I updated the answer- Not seen that before but it looks like thats how things are done now.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reconfiguring RPi and Samba using the setup shown here - http://www.megaleecher.net/Adding_External_USB_Disk_Drive_Storage_On_RasPi, this worked for me without any issues.

Comment: This was helpful, got me on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem, and was able to find a solution different from those posted above. I hope this is helpful to somebody else in a similar predicament

You mentioned that you were unable to change the permissions of the automounted folder - this is where the problem lies.

To fix, simply unmount the automounted drives by clicking the eject logo in the file explorer, or through the command line.

Then create a new folder in the media directory, I made mine "USBHDD1"

```
sudo mkdir /media/USBHDD1
```

Then mount the currently unmounted drive to this folder using

```
sudo mount -t auto /dev/sda1 /media/USBHDD1
```

Then you should be able to access the folder!