# Samba login not working

Tags: raspbian, networking, file-server

I'm trying to share a external harddrive on my pi. Followed this guide: http://www.simonthepiman.com/how_to_setup_windows_file_server_wheezy.php

All goes fine until i get to the part where I ad the network drive to Windows 7. I get the error "The network folder specified is currently mapped using a different user name and password.." (something like that, it's in Swedish so I had to translate)

Even when I go Network>Raspberrypi I see my usb folder but when I double click it I get "You don't have permission.."

My disk is ext4 if thats any help..

2012-10-28-wheezy-raspbian

Thanks for any help!

Comment: did you share any home folder too?

Comment: @AwesomeUser Sorry, this was so long ago I can't remember if I solved it.. You could delete this if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is exactly what you need but as this question has had no answers. Give the following [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3498/how-can-i-log-into-my-raspberry-pi-samba-fileshare-from-windows) a shot. Seems that the guy had the same problem as you now do. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are several way to mess with windows. Try simply resetting the connection using on Windows' command prompt:

```
net use /DELETE \\ServerName\ShareName
```

(or `net use /DELETE *` if you don't have / don't care about other mappings)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about security within your network, try setting your Samba configuration to allow anonymous users to mount shares.

Find the line that says "security = user" and update the file with the following lines

```
# "security = user" is always a good idea. This will require a Unix account
# in this server for every user accessing the server. See
# /usr/share/doc/samba-doc/htmldocs/Samba3-HOWTO/ServerType.html
# in the samba-doc package for details.
    security = share
    guest account = nobody
```

Then add a new share section at the bottom of your /etc/samba/smb.conf file that looks like this

```
[shared]
    comment = Shared drive on Raspberry Pi
    path = /path/to/your/drive/
    browseable = yes
    read only = no
    guest ok = yes
```

That will allow anyone on your LAN to mount the share read-write. If you get prompted for a username, choose Guest Account.