# Create fileserver for windows computer

Tags: networking, file-sharing

How can I create a file server (probably smb) so I can access a folder or drive from a windows computer on the same LAN?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried installing samba like this?

```
 sudo apt-get install samba
```

I Think this would solve your problem.

Comment: I did try samba after I posted this.  I got it installed but I am having trouble configuring it from a CLI... I don't have a gnome installed because I'm just using the Pi as a media server for my PS3.  I just want a way to add videos to it from my windows computer.

Comment: You don't need gnome, you just have to edit the samba configuration file /etc/samba/smb.conf . This [post](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3498/how-can-i-log-into-my-raspberry-pi-samba-fileshare-from-windows) and this [blog](http://chirale.wordpress.com/2012/08/31/turn-raspberry-into-a-small-nas-with-samba/) are helpful.